# PHP Search engines and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

As a newcomer to php and a search engine owner wannabe, I will suffer many headaches. I want to create my own search engine. I am trying with PHP and MYSQL to create an originally coded beta, but eventually I want to learn C++ so I can create my own table/searching system, like Google's Bigtable. My code should be somewhere on this post. Can somebody help me code?

```
                     The "PAGE" that does all the work
<?php
    $query = $_GET['S'];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","" ,""); 
    $i="";
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE keywords");
    explode(" ",$query); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        foreach ($i++ as $result){
            mysql_fetch_row(resource $result);
            $url = mysql_column['url'];
            $title= mysql_column['title'];
            $description= mysql_column['description'];
            $rating= mysql_column['rating'];
            echo '<a href=$url>$title</a><br>$description<br>Rating: $rating'; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "No Search Results."
?>
```

Comment: If you wanna ask something, ask it, whats the problem? Your question is "Anyone want to help me?" thats not a question for this page. go to a forum to try to gain adepts...

Comment: Good luck young padawan, I'd start first with something smaller, like not using `mysql_*`, but rather the more secure `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: if i can help in any way it would be by telling you to change your project, not only you will have many headackes, but it will be a great waste of time. A great beginner's project will be to build a simple blog, and well if you like search algorithms then add a simple search option to your blog to find posts by keywords and expand from there...

Answer (score 2):

Dont make your own search engine.  There are smarter people out there who created search engine and open sourced it. Google `Nutch`, `Solr` and `Lucene`